# summation of all $n$ digit number containing with digits?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, permutations

find sum of all ***$3$ digit numbers*** such that ***all digits are perfect square*** no digit being zero ?

---

i did this
$\{1,4,9\}$

at units place
$1 \to 2$ times
$4 \to 2$ times
$9 \to 2$ times
hence sum of digits at one's place$= 2\cdot 1+2\cdot 4+2\cdot9=28$

at tens place
$1 \to 2$ times
$4 \to 2$ times
$9 \to 2$ times
hence sum of digits at ten's place$= 2\cdot 1+2\cdot 4+2\cdot 9=28$

at hundreds place
$1 \to 2$ times
$4 \to 2$ times
$9 \to  2$ times
hence sum of digits at hundred's place$= 2\cdot 1+2\cdot 4+2\cdot 9=28$

therefore total sum is 
\begin{align}28100+28\cdot 10+28\cdot 1
&=28\cdot 111
\\&=3108
\end{align}

BUT THE ANSWER IS $13986$...
please explain

Comment: 0 is a perfect square.

Comment: @fleablood +1, yet I believe that still doesn't sum to what OP says it should.

Comment: @fleablood the answer $13986$ suggests one only count those with digits $1, 4, 9$. When $0$ is allowed, the answer becomes $24248$

Comment: @fleablood sorry i forgot to mention that no digit must be zero

Comment: Hint: If only $1,4,9$ are allowed to form numbers, there are totally 27 numbers to sum. nine of them has the form 1xx, nine has the form 4xx,  similar things happen to other digits and at different positions.

Comment: @achillehui ah i got it... it must be done with repetition... right? i was doing it without repetition

Comment: @VaniSharma yup, if the digits cannot repeat, the total sum will be $3108$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align} \sum_{i \in \{1,4,9\}} \sum_{j\in \{1,4,9\}} \sum_{k \in \{1,4,9\}} (100i + 10j +k) &= \sum_{i \in \{1,4,9\}} \sum_{j\in \{1,4,9\}}(300i + 30j+14)\\
&=\sum_{i \in \{ 1,4,9\}} (900 i+30(14)+14(3))\\
&=900(14)+99(14) \\
&=999(14)\\
&=14000-14\\
&= 13986\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

You are only counting numbers that are a permutation of $1,4,9$.  You have not counted numbers like $444$ or $441$ which have a matching pair of digits.  You should have $1$ in the units place counted $3^2=9$ times because each other place has $3$ choices, so the answer is $(1+4+9)999=14(1000-1)=13986$